# What do I do with this csv dataset I just downloaded from dbpedia?

Tags: php, data-mining, wikipedia

I just downloaded this csv of infoboxes of wikipedia from dbpedia. However I have no idea how to use it :-S I want to import all this data into a database but am not so sure how to take it from here. I downloaded it from http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads32#infoboxes

I'm working in Php

---

Just for the record - this csv file is around 1.8 GB. I'm actually going through all this trouble for well just to get a select set of infoboxes from a select set of articles form wikipedia. I would do it manually except I need the infoboxes for over 10 000 entries which includes countries and cities. I'm just looking for an easy way to do this and frankly have been using all my options :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import CSV data into MySQL you can use a [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement, e.g.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv'
INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, filed2, field3);
```

Sometimes such data might need a little massaging, it's not tricky to write a script in Perl or similar to parse a file line by line and spit out SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to massage the data before importing it, you could take a look at my CSV stream editor, [CSVfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) - it's FOSS. It can also generate SQL INSERT statements for your database if for some reason your database's bulk loading of CSV data doesn't suit you.